# How would you achieve this punk/distressed aesthetic?

Tags: print-design, patterns, texture, posters, halftone

I came across this poster online and I absolutely fell in love with the kind of blend of different textures coupled with this grunge aesthetic, do you have any idea how to recreate those effects ? I am talking about the halftone marks and the other little béavl shapes in front of the text. Thank you so much !

[image]

Comment: It's merely a collection of various textures layered on top of each other. Find a halftone texture, grunge texture, bar/QR code texture.. and stack them

Answer (score 1):

This design consists of different elements layered on top of each other.

When you want to learn from a design you like, try to break it down into its components:

### Type

[image]

Most of the poster consists of plain type in different sizes. The font looks like some kind of [Helvetica](https://www.fonts.com/font/linotype/helvetica) or similar.

### QR codes and barcodes

[image]

A few QR codes and barcodes of different types have been added. Probably just as decoration. Lots of sites offer free barcode generation. Like for example [TEC-IT Online Barcode Generator](https://barcode.tec-it.com/en/).

### Grunge texture

[image]

A grunge texture of sorts have been added in the left side. Search online for stuff like ["grunge texture"](https://www.google.com/search?q=grunge+texture&source=lnms&tbm=isch), ["splatter texture"](https://www.google.com/search?q=splatter+texture&source=lnms&tbm=isch), ["distressed texture"](https://www.google.com/search?q=distressed+texture&source=lnms&tbm=isch) etc.

### Halftone pattern

[image]

In the right side a shape with halftone pattern has been added. You can probably search online for texture, but they are easy to create yourself. Search this site for ["halftone pattern"](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/search?q=halftone+pattern) or find tutorials on [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=halftone).

### Folded paper texture

[image]

The whole design has had a folded paper texture added to make it look like a physical poster. Scan a folded and unfolded piece of paper or search for ["folded paper texture"](https://www.google.com/search?q=folded+paper+texture&source=lnms&tbm=isch)

### Method

I hope I've made it clear that this design really isn't especially complex. Just five different kinds of elements on top of each other.

You don't mention which application you are using so I can't really give you any specific tips.

In general:

- Let the typography be the main element.
- Use other elements as decoration.
- Gather a lot of different textures so you have something to choose from.
- Work in grayscale or use neutral images.
- Make sure all elements are completely black (not gray) in the darkest point to make things melt together.
- Stack elements on top of each other with blend mode *multiply*.
- Experiment with where to position elements to get a good balance.